How to update immersiveSpace from another window?
Hi I have 2 views and an Immersive space. 1st and 2nd views are display in a TabView I open my ImmersiveSpace from a button in the 1st view of the tab. Then When I go to 2nd TabView I want to show an attachment in my Immersive space. This attachment should be visible in Immersive space only as long as the user is on the 2nd view. This is what I have done so far
struct Second: View {
@StateObject var sharedImageData = SharedImageData()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
         // other code
     } .onAppear() {
        Task {
            sharedImageData.shouldCameraButtonShouw = true
        }
    }
    .onDisappear() {
        Task {
            sharedImageData.shouldCameraButtonShouw = false
        }
    }
}}

This is my Immersive space
struct ImmersiveView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var sharedImageData: SharedImageData

 var body: some View {
     RealityView { content, attachments in
     // some code
    } update: { content, attachments in
         guard let controlCenterAttachmentEntity = attachments.entity(for: Attachments.controlCenter) else { return }    
            controlCenterentity.addChild(controlCenterAttachmentEntity)
            content.add(controlCenterentity)
      } attachments: {

               if sharedImageData.shouldCameraButtonShouw {
            Attachment(id: Attachments.controlCenter) {
                ControlCenter()
            }
        }
        }
 }

}
And this is my Observable class
class SharedImageData: ObservableObject {
@Published var takenImage: UIImage? = nil
@Published var shouldCameraButtonShouw: Bool = false}

My problem is, when I am on Second view my attachment never appears. Attachment appears without this if condition. But How can I achieve my goal?

The attachment shouldn't be optional, adding it to the RealityView should be in the update when the condition is met
